# Why are "OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER" warnings getting logged in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'm seeing the following exception in C* logs and in all nodes. Is this something to do with System libraries ,..etc? BTW openSSL installed on all nodes is same and valid certs are in place.

Version : Cassandra-4.0.7
OS: Centos

```
WARN  [epollEventLoopGroup-5-9] 2023-01-23 09:42:32,537 PreV5Handlers.java:261 - \
  Unknown exception in client networking
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: \
  error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:478)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1309)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1270)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1346)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1389)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:206)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1387)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1294)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1331)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
"system.log" 6846L, 1121571B                                                                                                                                                                     6846,2-9      Bot
```

Anybody faced this? Please shed some light on that.

Thanks

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the most common cause of `SSLHandshakeException` warnings is when clients are connecting to the cluster with no SSL certificates.

Think of situations where you have monitoring enabled and the agents/daemons/process is trying to connect to an encrypted cluster but doesn't connect with SSL. This can also happen with client applications (usually with microservices) that connect to the cluster with no SSL.

You will need to identify the clients/applications connecting to the cluster which are not configured correctly.

Note that the messages are logged at `WARN` level (instead of `ERROR`) because there is no impact to the operation of the cluster. Only the misconfigured client/application is affected by this issue. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!